# Trying to customize wordpress drop down categories

Tags: php, css, javascript, html

I'm having some problems on how to display the categories that i want in wp_dropdown_categories.

Here is an image of the drop down -

> [image]

Here is the code for the dropdown -

**HTML:**

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

I tried placing this code in my functions.php and customize it but it doesn't seem to work. PHP is not my strong point.

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'walker'             => ''
); ?>
```

Comment: it is not very clear what are you trying to do. can you please edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: How are you placing in the scripts? Not directly in the PHP file right? You should use `wp_print_scripts`http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts and have that JS within that function. Try doing that and doing a simple alert to make sure it's rendering properly.